# Scrollable flexbox within another flexbox is not receiving the max height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a scrollable flexbox within another flexbox, considering that the scrollable flexbox depends on a tab choice. Like the image above:

[image: Page structure]

In image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0ZYF.png), the box "4" is my scrollable flexbox, and in yellow box there is a tab tool for selecting elements.

The problem is, when I fill box "4" with many entries, the page overflow and box scroll has only a small piece hide.

My CSS code:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}

.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.row {
}

.box .row.head {
    flex: 0 1 40px;
    background-color: red;
}

.box .row.mid {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    background-color: blue;
}

.box .row.foot {
    flex: 0 1 40px;
    background-color: green
}

.tab {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tabcontent{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.tabcontentheader {
    flex: 0 1 40px;
}

.tabcontentfooter {
    flex: 0 1 40px;
    #display: none;
}

.tabcontentmiddle{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row;
}

.colList {
    flex: 0 1 400px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: pink;
}
.colElement {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: pink;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.tab button{
    background-color: yellow;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16pfx;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0 5px 0px 0;
}

.tab button:hover {
    background-color: lime
}

.tab button.active {
    background-color: lime
}

.tabheader {
    display: none;
}

.tablist {
    display: none;
}

.tabelement {
    display: none;
}

.tabfooter {
    display: none;
}

.listtab1 {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.listtab1groupone {
    flex: 0 1 30px;
}

.listtab1groupthree {
    flex: 0 1 30px;
}

.listtab1grouptwo {
    flex: 0 1 30px;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.listtab1groupfour {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: max-content;
    border-style: solid;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    min-height: 0;
}

.elementList {
    height: 20px;
}
```

My page:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="row head">
        Page config
    </div>
    <div class="row mid">
        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab2')">Tab2</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab1')">Tab1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="tabcontent">
            <div class="tabcontentheader" id="tabcontentheader">
            </div>
            <div class="tabcontentmiddle">
                <div class="colList" id="colList">
                </div>
                <div class="colElement" id="colElement">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tabcontentfooter" id="tabcontentfooter">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row foot">
        Page save
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tabheader" id="tab1header">
    Export tool
</div>

<div class="tablist" id="tab1list">
    <div class="listtab1">
        <div class="listtab1groupone">
            Header list
        </div>
        <div class="listtab1grouptwo">
            Find tool
        </div>
        <div class="listtab1groupthree">
            Select All tool
        </div>
        <div class="listtab1groupfour">
            <div style="overflow-y:auto;">
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
                <div class="elementList"><input type="checkbox"/> Element1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tabelement" id="tab1element">
    Content 1
</div>

<div class="tabelement" id="tab1footer">
    Reload tool
</div>
```

And my js:

```
<script>
    function openTab(evt, tab) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabheader");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tablist");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabelement");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabfooter");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        
        document.getElementById("tabcontentheader").innerHtml='';
        if(document.getElementById(tab+'header') == null){
            document.getElementById("tabcontentheader").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("tabcontentheader").appendChild(document.getElementById(tab+'header'));
            document.getElementById(tab+'header').style.display = 'block'
        }
        
        document.getElementById("colList").innerHtml='';
        if(document.getElementById(tab+'list') == null){
            document.getElementById("colList").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("colList").appendChild(document.getElementById(tab+'list'));
            document.getElementById(tab+'list').style.display = 'block'
        }
        
        document.getElementById("colElement").innerHtml='';
        if(document.getElementById(tab+'element') == null){
            document.getElementById("colElement").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("colElement").appendChild(document.getElementById(tab+'element'));
            document.getElementById(tab+'element').style.display = 'block'
        }
        
        document.getElementById("tabcontentfooter").innerHtml='';
        if(document.getElementById(tab+'footer') == null){
            document.getElementById("tabcontentfooter").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("tabcontentfooter").appendChild(document.getElementById(tab+'footer'));
            document.getElementById(tab+'footer').style.display = 'block'
        }
        
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
</script>
```

When I open this page, my result is like image below, which is the right page.

[image: Right page]

However, when I click on Tab1, my result is like next image, which is not what I want.

[image: Wrong page]

How can I fix that behaviour of Tab1?

Comment: Do you want class `.tabcontentmiddle` to be the same size all the time? So it should not be stretched?

Comment: No. Class tabcontentmiddle height shoud change when I change window height. What I want is that the only elements which changes their height are tabcontentmiddle and, in this example, listtab1groupfour.

Answer (score 0):

So, as far as I understood, you want the box 4 to be smaller and scrollable.

```css
.listtab1groupfour {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: 400px;
    border-style: solid;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    min-height: 0;
    overflow: auto; 
}
```

And in your HTML get rid of that div right under `.listtab1groupfour`, the one with inline-styling. The trick was just to set a fixed height (e.g. 400px) and put `overflow: auto`.

Comment: And is it impossible to do that without fixed height? This box is the only not-fixed on the page. If I open the same page in a higher screen, will box fit the remaining space?

Comment: Well, how much do you want it to get big exactly? I don't understand what's the height limit you want that box to stop growing and beginning overflow-scrolling.

Comment: I don't know exactly how much. Let's say H1 is the browser screen height. Ignoring margins I want box4 height to be "H1 - height(row head) - height(tab) - height(tabcontentheader) - height(listtab1groupone) - height(listtab1grouptwo)-height(listtab1groupthree) - height(tabcontentfooter)  - height(row foot)".
All those are fixed.